# Join Two Table and count matching columns from table 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

I have two  tables and want the combined table based on both.

The table as it is....

```
Combine table last column
show count
from Table 2 columns (Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4, Subject5, Subject6)
where table1.course = table2.course match
```

The following picture shows the result:
[image]

**I am using `MS SQL` server 2008. I want to create a SQl Query and save it as Views so that I can use it in a `vb.net` windows application and show it through RDLC report......**

Comment: will you always have 6 subjects columns in Table 2 or will the number of columns change.

Comment: thanks 4 response, YES 6 subject columns fixed

Comment: Also what version of SQL-Server are you using?

Comment: you have a picture and it is still 100% unclear what you want.  How do the tables join -- is table1.subject related to table2.subject2?

Comment: Yes, table 1 having exam scheme and table 2 having students data. what i want to create exam scheme with number of student in per subject so that seeting plan can be made. Actually every student is have choice to select subject as per their class.

Comment: Is your Table1 complete?  Should there be a record for 7/3/2016  BA1  ENV in there?

Comment: Also, why do you show a count of 1 for 6/3/2016 BA3 HIS in your result table?  There is no HIS for BA3 in Table2.

Comment: yes it is their sorry by mistaken typed wrong its as u explain.

Comment: Sorry Again, actually I created manually to explanation purpose.
In Combine Table, I want the column of table 1 as it is (3 columns) and check from 6 columns with the subject column of table 1 and show counted value in combine table column 4.

Comment: is there possible to count from one more table and show at last. the table3 also have same structure as table2. IF possible please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this query a try:

```
select t.Edate,
t.Course,
t.Subject,
sum(case when t.Subject = t2.Subject1 or t.Subject = t2.Subject2 or t.Subject = t2.Subject3 or t.Subject = t2.Subject4 or t.Subject = t2.Subject5 or t.Subject = t2.Subject6 then 1 else 0 end) [Count]
from Table1 t
join Table2 t2 on t.Course = t2.Course
group by t.Edate, t.Course, t.Subject
order by t.Edate, t.Course
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58f68/1)

Comment: what happens when the joining subjects are on different rows (like MA1 and A in example data)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Did you look at my fiddle?  The results are pretty much what he wanted (keeping in mind that he acknowledged that his example data wasn't entirely correct).

Comment: ah well, no way to know what he wanted if the sample data was wrong, good job reading his mind.

Comment: is there possible to count from one more table and show at last. the table3 also have same structure as table2. IF possible please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this example instead:

```
SELECT     dbo.table1.Edate, dbo.table1.Course, dbo.table1.Subject AS SubjectTitle, COUNT(dbo.table2.Subject1) AS Subject1, COUNT(dbo.table2.Subject2) AS Subject2, COUNT(dbo.table2.Subject3) 
                      AS Subject3, COUNT(dbo.table2.Subject4) AS Subject4, COUNT(dbo.table2.Subject5) AS Subject5, COUNT(dbo.table2.Subject6) AS Subject6
FROM         dbo.table1 CROSS JOIN
                      dbo.table2
GROUP BY dbo.table1.Edate, dbo.table1.Course, dbo.table1.Subject
```

Comment: Thanx 4 response, NO its not. i want 2 check all 6 columns.

Comment: is there possible to count from one more table and show at last. the table3 also have same structure as table2. IF possible please help

Answer (score 0):

Probably this

```
WITH subjectList AS
(
  SELECT course, Subject1 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject2 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject3 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject4 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject5 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject6 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
)
SELECT T1.Edate, T1.course, sl.subject, count(*) as subject_count
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN subjectList sl on T1.Course = sl.course and T1.Subject = sl.subject
GROUP BY T1.Edate, T1.course, sl.subject
```

might be this

```
WITH subjectList AS
(
  SELECT course, Subject1 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject2 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject3 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject4 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject5 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT course, Subject6 as subject 
  FROM TABLE2
)
SELECT T1.Edate, T1.course, sl.subject, 
       count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY T1.course, sl.subject) as subject_by_course_count,
       count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY sl.subject) as subject_count
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN subjectList sl on T1.Course = sl.course and T1.Subject = sl.subject
GROUP BY T1.Edate, T1.course, sl.subject
```

Comment: is there possible to count from one more table and show at last. the table3 also have same structure as table2. IF possible please help

Comment: @SantoshPandey -- this question is closed -- you posted your own answer and marked someone else as the correct answer -- how in the world do you expect me to help?  post a new question that states what you are looking for clearly.

Answer (score 0):

thanx all,
i solved it with your help, if some one wants this
here it is:

```
    select t.Edate,t.Etime,
t.Course,
t.Subject,t.Paper,t.Code,
sum(case when t2.adcat = 'Regular' AND  t.Subject = S.Subject then 1 else 0 end) [Reg],
sum(case when t2.adcat = 'Private' AND  t.Subject = S.Subject then 1 else 0 end) [Pri],
sum(case when t2.adcat = 'Ex.' AND  t.Subject = S.Subject then 1 else 0 end) [Ex],
sum(case when t2.adcat = 'Back Paper' AND  t.Subject = S.Subject then 1 else 0 end) [BP],
sum(case when t2.adcat = 'Single Subject' AND  t.Subject = S.Subject then 1 else 0 end) [SS],
sum(case when t2.adcat = 'Improvement' AND  t.Subject = S.Subject then 1 else 0 end) [Imp]
from EXAMscheme t
join tblstudetail t2 CROSS APPLY(VALUES (subjectI), (subjectII), (subjectIII), (subjectIV), (subjectV), (subjectVI)) AS S(subject)
on t.Course = t2.Course and
 t.session = t.session and
  t.session = '2015-16' and 
  t2.session = '2015-16' AND
  t2.EXstatus = 'OK'
group by t.Edate,t.Etime,t.Paper,t.Code, t.Course, t.Subject
order by t.Edate, t.Course
```

Comment: one thing more. Is it possible to add total of all counts at last column and grand total of single Date at the final last column as shown in my code. PLEASE HELP

Comment: is there possible to count from one more table and show at last. the table3 also have same structure as table2. IF possible please help